# How would I run lsvirtualenv or any of the other virtualenvwrapper functions via python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm attempting to run `virtualenvwrapper.sh` commands (ie: lsvirtualenv and mkvirtualenv).

I attempted to use

```
subprocess.call(["lsvirtualenv"])
```

but it does not seem to work. It gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importMaster.py", line 6, in <module>
    virtualEnvs = subprocess.call(["lsvirtualenv"])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Since these functions are inside of the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file, how would I go about referencing the function in a python script?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh) && <your command>` with `shell=True`.

**Example:**

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> p = Popen("source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh) && lsvirtualenv", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
>>> print(p.stdout.read())
10leds
======


ambientlight
============
```

See the documentation for the [Popen Constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: Is Popen not deprecated? I thought subprocess was meant to replace Popen and several other older modules

Comment: @Edasaur You are thinking of ``os.popen`` and friends.

Comment: A higher level wrapper around subprocess like the `sh` module is my favorite route nowadays.

Comment: OH. So there's another popen constructor? Oh that makes so much sense!

Thank you! I will try this out and if it doesn't work, get back to you.

Comment: @PauloScardine My favourite is Fabric :)

Comment: Ah sorry for doubting you :)

Thanks so much! :)